# Imported Multibit HD wallet into electrum - Bitcoins are gone!

Tags: electrum, wallet-recovery, multibit-hd

I got locked out of my multibit HD wallet and couldn't restore it with the seed phrase (even though it said they're valid) so I installed electrum and used the seed words to import the wallet. It worked but the bitcoins have disappeared. Is there a way I can recover them?

Comment: Do the addresses that you have look like your addresses? It is likely that you are using the wrong derivation path as Multibit HD and Electrum use different default derivation paths.

Comment: If you cannot see the history, calm down, it's just some keypath issue, you'll find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Try restoring again. To do that you have to create a new wallet file via file > new/restore, enter a unique filename and click next. Then be mindful of the following things:

- On the seed entry step click on options and check bip39. Pay attention to the message next to the options button in this step. When it says bip39 checksum OK you can proceed to the next step.
- In the next step enter a derivation path of m/0' . That’s a zero and a single quote.